# Is it possible to replace a word before a phrase using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Input text: `Engineering School, Medical school`

Output required: `Educational school, Educational school`

Rule: any words before the phrase `school` (case insensitive) needs to be replaced by `Educational`

```
$inputext = "Engineering School, Medical school"; 
$rule ="//s/";
$replacetext = "Educational";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo($outputext);
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `$rule ="//s/";` is not a valid regex. You should have got the *preg_replace(): Unknown modifier `'/'`* warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/\w+(?= school)/i` pattern in regex that select any word before `school`.

```
$inputext = "Engineering school, Medical school"; 
$rule ="/\w+(?= school)/i";
$replacetext = "Educational";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/btX8j)

Also you can use `/\w+(?= school(,|$))/i` to prevent matching undesired word like `schoolboy` as @WiktorStribiżew said.

Comment: How can i make it case insensitive. so any occurance of School or school should be dealt with

Comment: @user4826347 Use `i` flag in regex pattern. `/\w+(?= school)/i`

Comment: If you don't want to use flags do: `\w+(?= school| School)`

Comment: `/\w+(?= school)/i` will also replace the word before `schoolboy` and will not match a word if it is followed with 2 spaces and `school`. `\w+(?= school| School)` is a poor pattern as the branches inside one group should not match at the same location in the string. Also, one would use `\w+(?= [sS]chool)` if `ScHoOl` should not be matched.

Comment: `\w+(?= [sS]chool([\s,;.]|$))` will prevent words such as schoolboy.